# uitableviewcell imageview image not showing on startup

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uiimageview, ios7, afnetworking

So I'm Using UIImageView+AFNetwrking  from my viewdidLoad to download my images from an Api  and in my cellforRowAtIndexPath method using the setImageWithUrl method to set each cells image views image, but the images don't all appear directly after the controller loads.

Only when I select a cell in My tableView does each image Appear in each of my cells imageView.

How do I get the Images in my cells to appear all at once directly after the view loads.

Here us my uitableviewcell subclass

```
@implementation UIMeCell
@synthesize MoveObject=_MoveObject;
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
if (self) {
    // Initialization code
    self.textLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
    self.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    self.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    self.textLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
    self.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0f];
    self.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray;
 }
return self;
}
-(void)setMoveObject:(UIMoveObject *)MoveObject{
_MoveObject = MoveObject;
self.textLabel.text = self.MoveObject.MovieTitle;
 [self.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:_MoveObject.MoviePoster] placeholderImage:       
[UIImage imageNamed:@"image"]];
    [self setNeedsDisplay];

 }
-(void)layoutSubviews{
 [super layoutSubviews];
 self.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,32,32);
 }
```

My ViewController Class

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{   
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.baseUrls = base_rr;


 if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(edgesForExtendedLayout)])
    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;

 [theTableView registerClass:[UIMeCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
[theTableView setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone];


[self refresh]; 
}
-(void)refresh{
self.MovieArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
theNavigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.enabled = NO;
NSURLSessionDataTask * task = [UIFlickConnect MovieListWithUrl:TOP_Rated andParameters:   
[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:API_KEY,@"api_key", nil] andBlock:^(NSArray* err,    
NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        self.MovieArray = [err mutableCopy];
              [theTableView reloadData];
         theNavigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.enabled = YES;
}
}];

[UIAlertView showAlertViewForTaskWithErrorOnCompletion:task delegate:nil];

UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicatorView = (UIActivityIndicatorView *)    
theNavigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.customView;
[activityIndicatorView setAnimatingWithStateOfTask:task];

}

-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath    
 *)indexPath{
NSString *cellidentifier  = @"Cell";
UIMeCell *cell;
cell = [theTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellidentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
if (!cell) {
    cell = [[UIMeCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault      
 reuseIdentifier:cellidentifier];
}

NSMutableDictionary * dictionary  = [[self.MovieArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] mutableCopy];
[dic setValue:[self.baseUrls stringByAppendingString:dic[@"poster_path"]]     
forKey:@"poster_path"];

UIMoveObject * object = [[UIMoveObject alloc] initWithDictionary:dictionary];
cell.MoveObject = object;


return cell;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that ``setMoveObject`` is getting called when you assign the object in ``cellForRowAtIndexPath``?

Comment: You should also check that ``self.imageView`` is initialized when you call ``setImageWithURL``. Also, check that your ``UIImageView``object has the proper frame to display the image.

Comment: Thanks for helping amb. I was able to solve the problem by downloading all the images into  a separate array  in a method right after downloading the necessary urls and then when all the images were downloaded I refreshed the tableView.

Comment: It is not necessary to perform a ``UITableView`` refresh when you receive the images. I think that you are doing something wrong with your table. Remember that setting the image in your ``UIImageView`` should be necessary to display the image.